# How to call a page-object from a class.rb at Support folder

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am using the page-object gem. Suppose i have a page-object on `features/bussines/pages/booking_page.rb` for a page like:

```
class Booking

   include PageObject

   span(:txtFirstName,   :id => 'details_first_name')

end
```

...and i use a "tools" class located at `features/support/tools.rb` with something like:

```
class MyTools

  def call_to_page_object
    on Booking do |page|
       puts page.txtFirstName
    end
  end
end
```

...but this approach fails because calling to the object from the class is not allowed:

```
undefined method `on' for #<Booking:0x108f5b0c8> (NoMethodError)
```

Pretty sure i'm missing some concept on the way to use the page-object from a class but don't realize whats the problem. Can you please give me an idea about what could be wrong here, please?

Thank you very much!

============================

Justin found the reason why the call to the class crash. The final class code results:

```
class MyTools

  #Include this module so that the class has the 'on' method
  include PageObject::PageFactory

  def initialize(browser)
    #Assign a browser object to @browser, which the 'on' method assumes to exist
    @browser = browser
  end

  def getCurrentRewards
    on Booking do |page|
      rewards_text = page.rewards_amount
      rewards_amount = rewards_text.match(/(\d+.*\d*)/)[1].to_f
      puts "The current rewards amount are: #{rewards_amount}."
      return rewards_amount
    end
  end

end
```

And the call to the function:

```
user_rewards = UserData.new(@browser).getCurrentRewards
```

Why it did not work me? Two main reasons:

- I didn't pass the browser object to the class <== REQUIRED
- I didn't include the PageObject::PageFactory in the class <== REQUIRED for the "on" method.

Thanks all!

Comment: Edited the first question to add how the class looks after Željko comments; still not working.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want to do. You want to reuse code in step definition file? Then you should reuse it there, not create a separate class.

Comment: The function "getCurrentRewards" can be called from many steps definitions and from many page objects (it returns the Rewards a user have). To get this data, the function have to know the value of a page element (in the example "rewards_amount") that is defined on an object (in the example, the object "Booking").

Calling the function, i can know the user rewards from several Scenarios. If the calling to the Page object from the separate class works, i can access to many elements of different objects with one unique class, if needed. Hope it were more clear; if not, just ask. Thanks Zeljko!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `on` (or [`on_page`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/PageFactory#on_page-instance_method)) method requires two things:

1. The method to be available, which is done by including the `PageObject::PageFactory` module.
2. Having a `@browser` variable (within the scope of the class) that is the browser.

So you could make your MyTools class work by doing:

```
class MyTools
  #Include this module so that the class has the 'on' method
  include PageObject::PageFactory

  def initialize(browser)
    #Assign a browser object to @browser, which the 'on' method assumes to exist
    @browser = browser
  end

  def call_to_page_object
    on Booking do |page|
       puts page.txtFirstName
    end
  end
end
```

You would then be calling your MyTools class like:

```
#Assuming your Cucumber steps have the the browser stored in @browser:
MyTools.new(@browser).call_to_page_object
```

Comment: Hi Justin!
If using `include PageObject::PageFactory`i get the error:
`Unable to pick a platform for the provided browser (RuntimeError)`


If using just `include PageObject`, i get the error:
`undefined method 'on' for #<UserData:0x103ec8ac0> (NoMethodError)`


The @browser variable is set on the env.rb file, so i think i should not initialize it on the class. More over, when the execution calls the MyTools class, the browser is already opened. Am i right?

Comment: The @browser variable has to exist in the class or else you will get the `Unable to pick a platform` error. Initializing your browser (ie @browser) in the env.rb file is fine, but you still have to pass the browser object to the class since the `on` method assumes that it exists for initializing the page object (ie Booking) - see the [source](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/PageFactory#on_page-instance_method).

Comment: The `on` method is defined in the `PageObject::PageFactory` module. If you do just `include PageObject`, I do not believe it includes the `PageFactory`. You need to do `include PageObject::PageFactory`.

Comment: You're absolutely right and you nailed it. As i wrote in the question, i miss to pass the browser object to the class and to include the module PageObject::PageFactory. Thank you so much, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do?

Did you read [Cucumber & Cheese](https://leanpub.com/cucumber_and_cheese) book?

Pages should be in the `features/support/pages` folder. You can put other files that pages need there too.

If you want to use `on` method in a class, you have to add this to the class:

```
include PageObject
```

The code from MyTools class looks to me like it should be in Cucumber step file, not in a class.

Comment: Hi Željko!
What i'm trying to do is to call a page element from a kind of tools.rb file. The code i wrote is an example, it was taken from a step file, you're right. I'm close to end the "Cucumber book Pragmatic programing" book and the next one is the Cheezy one.
Following your recommendations, i've moved the pages folder inside support and insert the _include PageObject_. After that i get a:
_wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)_ I'll paste the "real" code in the main question. Still looking for whats wrong... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your class should use the `extend` keyword to access special class methods like `span`:

```
class Booking
   extend PageObject
   span(:txtFirstName, :id => 'details_first_name')
end
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Hi Christopher! "extend" does not solve the problem, having the same _undefined method "on"_ message. I think Booking does not "extend" PageObject but should include it. Thanks for the answer; i'll post the solution once found :)